# Ошибка в подключаемой бибилиотеке в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, lib

Пишу свою библиотеку и в ней использую стороннюю библиотеку loping, в про файле либы его подключаю все это делаю. Когда подключаю либу к проекту, начинает ругаться на функции этой библиотеки. Прикрепляю про файлы проектов.
pro файл либы

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++11

CONFIG += adtlib

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

win32 {
    SOURCES += WIN\ADTComponent.cpp
    SOURCES += WIN\ADTNode.cpp
    LIBS += -lws2_32
    LIBS += -liphlpapi
}

unix {
    SOURCES += LIN/ADTComponent.cpp
    SOURCES += LIN/ADTNode.cpp
    LIBS    += -loping
}

HEADERS += \
    include/ADTComponent.h \
    include/ADTNode.h

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

pro файл проекта где проверяю либу

```
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

LIBS += -loping

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

INCLUDEPATH += /home/danila/Qt/Projects/ADTLib/include
LIBS += /home/danila/Qt/Projects/build-ADTLib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Release/libADTLib.a
```

Сама функция которая не работает

```
{
  bool res = false;

      pingobj_t *pingobj = ping_construct();

      int timeout = 4;
      for (;;)
        {
          double timeout_sec = ((double)timeout)/(double)(1000.0);

          if (ping_setopt(pingobj, PING_OPT_TIMEOUT, &timeout_sec))
            break;

          if (ping_host_add(pingobj, host.toStdString().c_str()))
            break;

          if (ping_send(pingobj) <= 0)
            break;

          res = true;

          break;
        }

      ping_destroy(pingobj);

      return res;
}
```

main.cpp где проверяю

```
#include <ADTNode.h>
#include <oping.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  pingToHost("127.0.0.1");

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: А ошибку нам самим придумать?

Comment: пишет что не найдены функции из либы и перечисляет функции из loping

Comment: саму библиотеку собрали? куда положили?

Comment: вообще пишет /home/danila/Qt/Projects/ADTLib/LIN/ADTNode.cpp:-1: ошибка: undefined reference to `ping_construct' и так с каждой функцией библиотеки loping

Comment: ну, то что я сделал видно по тексту выше. Я не знаю как это исправить

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application/ru